# Bundle Product Quantity not load

Tags: magento-1.9, product, quantity, server-setup, bundle

I make bundle products in Magento with **in stock**.

When I try to add to cart so it displays error:

> the requested for x product not available

and it is on my live server not in localhost Xampp server.

I didn't understand what the problem is. Can anyone give suggestions?

Comment: in magento which version?.

Comment: magento 1.9 Gokul K

Comment: I think some bundle items don't have enough qty?

Comment: If any one bundle product qty is low so whole 600 bundles get this error i think this is not the reason.. MageX